# Playing local audio from an Apple phone

Tags: iphone, audio

I have a telephone called ''I-Phone 5s'' that I want to
use to play my own audio files, which I have on a computer running
(Arch) Linux.  I prefer not to use any cloud.  How do I do that?

Comment: Tell us what you have already tried, and the results, in detail. Add that to your question.

Answer (score 2):

What I do in a similar case (iPhone5s <--> Linux):

1. on the phone, download the free version of [FE File Explorer](https://www.skyjos.com/fileexplorer/) app
2. open FE, create a folder in Local > On My iPhone
3. connect the phone to the computer using usb
4. copy files from the computer to the folder in FE on the phone
5. in FE, click an audio file to play

(3) works out of the box on Ubuntu MATE 18.04. On an older Ubuntu version, I have to use wifi and samba for file transfer.